# Is more of a computer task correct?

Tags: comparative-constructions

Let's say my professor gives me a question in math requiring complicated programming. Then I want to tell her that it is 80% computer work.

Is it correct to say that it is more of a computer task?

Or, do I have to say it is more of a computer task than a math task?

Comment: More of a computer task than *what*? Aside: you don't have to tell your professor what is involved, because she knows more about the task. Oops... she knows *more than you* about the task.

Comment: more of a computer task than a math task.

Comment: You could say "It's mostly *computation*".